# Visual Studio LTSC 17.2 Feature 'static local functions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working in C# on the .NET Framework in the Console App for Microsoft Visual Studio. I am noticing the error below and I am unable to figure out where to fix that.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS8370  Feature 'static local functions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

I have updated Microsoft Visual Studio whereas the error still occurs.

Comment: .net framework I don’t think will ever support that since there were clr changes

Comment: I was able to work on the same type of c# file a few days ago. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Sure but was that targeting .net 6?

Comment: Static local functions (or local functions in general, for that matter) don't require runtime support, so you can slip `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` (or a higher version) into a PropertyGroup in the project file and it will allow the feature to be used regardless of target runtime version.

Comment: @DanielA.White `static` local functions are a compiler feature, so it's fine to use them with .NET Framework. Local functions are still just methods at the end of the day. You can use sharplab.io to decompile to C# and see how this works if you're curious.

Comment: The version of C# that's available to you is not based solely on the version of VS in use. Rather, it's based on the target framework you've set. However that is just a default. You can override it via the `<LangVersion>` property as described. Note that this is not always supported by Microsoft, but in my experience works well.

Comment: It is true that certain modern C# language features will not work on all target frameworks. Default interface members, for example, do require runtime support.

Comment: @j-d Is there any update in this issue? Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As madreflection said, generally this kind of "CS8370 Feature 'XXXX' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater." error, just need to add a line of code in csproj.

Try adding `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` or `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in your ConsoleAppX.csproj under the `<PropertyGroup>` node.